# Why name endpoints in sveltekit .json.js?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

I've seen naming endpoints in sveltekit with .json.js. Why? .js should be enough, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an old convention from earlier days to double the extension with the format of the returned data (data.json.js, data.xml.js) but is no longer used. I believe before it would even put the correct headers based on the extension, but think that is no longer the case.

You *can* of course still do this to make it clear to consumers what they will get back:

```js
// I know I will get a json object from this because it says so in the name
const res = await fetch('something/products.json');
```